# How to display reports (Html.ReportViewer) properly in bootstrap?

Tags: c#, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor, reporting-services

I have a following problem. I want to create 3x3 table(or view) with `@Html.ReportViewer`  inside. I want to display all of report without a scrolls.

I have following code in my controller:

ReportViewer rptViewer = new ReportViewer();

```
        rptViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
        rptViewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
        rptViewer.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.FullPage;

        rptViewer.AsyncRendering = false;

        //Dodatki okna:
        rptViewer.ShowBackButton = false;
        rptViewer.ShowExportControls = false;
        rptViewer.ShowFindControls = false;
        rptViewer.ShowPageNavigationControls = false;
        rptViewer.ShowPrintButton = false;
        rptViewer.ShowRefreshButton = false;
        rptViewer.ShowZoomControl = false;

        rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("MyServerAddress");
        rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "MyReportPath";

        rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportViewerCredentials("MyCredentials");


        ViewBag.ReportViewer = rptViewer;
        return View();
```

And this is my view code and view as I see:
[image]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
       @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)
    </div>
</div>
```

Only the last element is without scrolls. The rest are a small windows with scrolls. How to fix this situation? Can I do a nice view with ReportViewer elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a following code into my view it solved a problem:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, new { frameborder = "0", width = "500", height = "500", style = "overflow:hidden;", scrolling = "no" })
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer1 as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, new { frameborder = "0", width = "500", height = "500", style = "overflow:hidden;", scrolling = "no" })
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, new { frameborder = "0", width = "500", height = "500", style = "overflow:hidden;", scrolling = "no" })
</div>
```